# Loop through dictionary values in my function

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary (called oxygen_position_dict) consisting of the following:

```
 {'a': (0, 0, 0), 'b': (3.3, 0, 0), 'c': (3.3, 0, 3.3), 'd': (0, 0, 3.3)}
```

I also have a fixed tuple I've called k_1

```
 k_1 = (1.65, 8.25, 1.65)
```

and I'm trying to have a for loop iterate through the values in my dictionary, and perform my distance function calculation only on the values (below)

```
 def distance(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2):
     return sqrt(((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2 + (z1 - z2)**2))
```

Below is my attempt:

```
 for x in oxygen_position_dict.values():
      print(distance(*(x + k_1)))
```

However, the output is

```
 8.573651497465942
 8.573651497465942
 8.573651497465942
 8.573651497465942
```

which is only the output for the distance calculation of the first dictionary value!

How do I get it to iterate through my entire set of values, holding k_1 constant? Thanks for any help!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. The distance between 0 and 1.65 is the same as the distance between 3.3 and 1.65. So you get the same result 4 times.

Comment: Yes, it can correspond to either, but here it is x2, y2, z2.

Comment: @biop91 Try manual calculation or change `k_1` a bit and you will see `distance` is doing its job nicely.

Comment: It makes sense if chemical elements in the first list are the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the tuples passe to your function are

```
(0, 0, 0, 1.65, 8.25, 1.65)
(3.3, 0, 0, 1.65, 8.25, 1.65)
(3.3, 0, 3.3, 1.65, 8.25, 1.65)
(0, 0, 3.3, 1.65, 8.25, 1.65)
```

that gives the differences of your vectors as

```
(-1.65, -8.25, -1.65)
(1.65, -8.25, -1.65)
(1.65, -8.25, 1.65)
(-1.65, -8.25, 1.65)
```

now adding the square of those will give the same result.

---

using `scipy` you would get the distance for free:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance

for x in oxygen_position_dict.values():
    print(distance.euclidean(k_1, x))
```

---

also `numpy` could make things easier:

```
import numpy as np

oxygen_position_dict = {'a': np.array((0, 0, 0)), 
                        'b': np.array((3.3, 0, 0)),
                        'c': np.array((3.3, 0, 3.3)),
                        'd': np.array((0, 0, 3.3))}

k_1 = np.array((1.65, 8.25, 1.65))

for x in oxygen_position_dict.values():
    print(np.linalg.norm(k_1 - x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently (after some testing), it so happens that your code is fine! The main problem is that all your values have the same distance. I tried manually doing the calculations and it seems as such. So either you are really lucky with the values, or the distance() is not working right.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code:

import math

```
def distance(p0, p1):
    return math.sqrt((p0[0] - p1[0])**2 + (p0[1] - p1[1])**2 + (p0[2] - p1[2])**2)

d =  {'a': (0, 0, 0), 'b': (3.3, 0, 0), 'c': (3.3, 0, 3.3), 'd': (0, 0, 3.3)}
k_1 = (1.65, 8.25, 1.65)

for k,v in d.items():
    print(k,'-',distance(k_1,v))
```

Output:

```
a - 8.573651497465942
b - 8.573651497465942
c - 8.573651497465942
d - 8.573651497465942
```

All your distance values are same.